# Performance of query job using Bulk API V1 vs Bulk API v2

Tags: bulk-api, bulk-api-v2

I am currently using Bulk API v1 query job to extract data out of Salesforce. In this case by using pkChunking, extract job of 150k records completes within 30-40 seconds. However, now when I am planning to move to Bulk API v2, for extracting same data it is taking more than 6minutes(see attached screenshot). Can this time be reduced to be inline with the Bulk API v1 performance?

In case of Bulk API v1, by using pkChunking header we were able to split data into batches & it was faster, I don't see this behaviour in bulk api v2.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce Documentation States

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/queries.htm)

> "Bulk API 2.0 query jobs enable asynchronous processing of SOQL queries. Bulk API 2.0 is optimized to chunk large query jobs if the object being queried supports chunking.

> The API automatically handles retries. If you receive a message that the API retried more than 15 times, apply a filter criteria and try again."

However, the timings you observe on the "**Monitor Bulk Data Load Jobs**" could vary broadly based on the resource availability on the instance the job is running on.

> At present there is no guarantee or SLA on Bulk API batch processing time because the asynchronous processes depend on the server resource availability as per [The Force.com Multitenant Architecture](https://architect.salesforce.com/fundamentals/platform-multitenant-architecture) .

Supporting Articles below:

[Varying SLA Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000388528&language=en_US&type=1)

[Description of Asynchronous processing in Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384188&type=1)